# bcp in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, bcp

I have a local .csv file that has the following content:

[image]

This file is located at `C:\Desktop\name_table.csv` on my pc.

Then I want to use bcp to upload the content in this .csv file to Microsoft Azure SQL database.
I created a table called `test` in my Azure SQL database, and it has two columns, "name" and "ID".
Then I used the following command in the Azure built-in console:

`bcp mydatabase.dbo.test in C:\Desktop\name_table.csv -S ****.database.windows.net -U **** -P **** -q -c -t`

I got the following result:

[image]

It says "0 rows copied", but there are 4 rows in my .csv file.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that might be of interest here:

- Make sure the CSV uses the expected delimiter
- Check to see if the column data types are correct
- Make sure the csv file uses the ASCII or UTF-16 encoding since bcp does not support UTF-8.

More information: [Load data from CSV into Azure SQL Database or SQL Managed Instance (flat files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/load-from-csv-with-bcp)